# Equivalent of Django Signals for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, django, callback, observer-pattern

In Rails, the closest I've seen to [Django Signals](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) are [Observers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html). The problem with them is that they're restricted to triggering callbacks on hardcoded events related to a model's lifecycle.

Django signals can be created anywhere, triggered anywhere and handled anywhere. The model lifecycle callbacks are just regular signals that happen to come built-in and that are triggered by the ORM.

Does anyone know of a similarly general solution for Rails? It could be some generic Ruby library, not tied to Rails, which would be even better.

---

Edit: Observer is the closest thing, but it's not what I'm looking for. It's a one-to-many solution. Anyone can listen, but only the originating object can post. I'd like something where you declare a signal, and anyone can trigger it as well as handle it. Also, I don't like the fact that the Ruby Observer dictates that the handler have an #update method. I'd like to be able to pass any method reference with the appropriate signature.

I could use the Ruby Observer to implement my own such broker, but I'm trying to learn if someone already did it.

Comment: It's just the Observer pattern, which is part fo the Ruby standard libs, rather than Rails. Rails Observers are a special, convention-over-configuration case, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a closer equivalent than Rails' Observer is the [standard Ruby Observable module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/observer/rdoc/index.html). It lets you add a list of observers to an object and the object can then send notifications to the observers when it changes.

Answer (score 1):

What about the 'wisper' gem? https://github.com/krisleech/wisper

> Wisper is a Ruby library for decoupling and managing the dependencies
> of your Ruby objects using Pub/Sub.
>
> It is commonly used as an alternative to ActiveRecord callbacks and
> Observers to reduce coupling between data and domain layers.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps acts_as_state machine will help.  Most of this functionality has recently been baked into Rails edge.

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented a gem with that. https://github.com/pkoch/django_signal/

Answer (score 0):

Ruby gem 'watchable' is the most appropriate choice
https://github.com/jbarnette/watchable

It has a syntax that is very familiar to Django's (and other frameworks, like Qt and many others).